# jpa Hibernate @ElementCollection

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa-2.0

I have a question which bothers me a bit.

When i use @ElementCollection in my entity hibernate (3.5) generates me a table without any constraints.

**Important Edit**

My Entity is a subclass of another class. That is maybe the reason why hibernate does not generate the pk and the fk.

**Edit End**

```
public MyEntity extends BaseEntity
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<String> test;
```

Ends up with (postgres 9):

```
CREATE TABLE myentity_test
(
  entityid bigint NOT NULL,
  test character varying(255)
)
```

Is this my mistake that hibernate doesn't set any constraints like foreign keys or unique indexes?
I could set it manually, but i would prefer to annotate the entity correctly that hibernate completely (as much as possible) creates my database.

Best regards,
m

PS: My Bad at all. Mixed up two things which where going around in my mind. i meant @ElementCollection.

PS: The @Column helped to deliver the unique index. Edit: corrected the names to my example.

```
CREATE TABLE myentity_test
(
  entityid bigint NOT NULL,
  test character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT itemequipable_test_test_key UNIQUE (test)
)
```

I would expect something like this (pseudo code):

```
CREATE TABLE myentity_test
(
  entityid bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  test character varying(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  CONSTRAINT fk_entityid references (myentity) on entityid
)
```

Comment: Your example code does not use @Enumerated

Comment: Foreign key is created by separate `ALTER TABLE` statement, perhaps you missed it.

Comment: However I believe you just need an @Column annotation which you can set nullable=false etc. on it should you so wish.

Comment: @David: Exactly so. Should be an answer.

Comment: I copied the definition of the table after creation. The @Column helped and i have the unique contraint now. The fk is still missing. Sorry for the confusion at beginning. ;-)

Comment: No worries.  Happy to help.  The Hibernate documentation is comprehensive but you have to take a lot of care over the fine detail.  I would advise trying to work with the JPA standard where at all possible & recommend the Apress book 'Pro JPA 2...'.

Comment: i already have the book and i try to stay at jpa2. i just couldn't figure out why i get no pk and foreign key back to the entity the collection belongs to. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Column and @JoinColum/@OneToMany annotations are the correct way to handle the foreign keys and unique constraints, even with the @ElementCollection.

In your particular example, there is not going to be a foreign key relationship because String (the type of your Set) is not mapped to another entity.

Comment: Good spot.   Yes.  Where the type (xxx) is not evident you would require (..., targetEntity= xxx).  Although an entity equivalent to String is difficult to imagine.

Comment: With foreign key i meant that from the collection table there should be a foreign key back to the entityid and a primary key over entityid and test.

Comment: I found out that when i change my inheritance strategy back to single_table the collection table will be generated correctly. Maybe there is an issue with hbm2ddl. works fine now. thanks a lot for all helpers!